# Jquery Mobile 1.4.0 client side session handling

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am implementing a simple mobile web app using jquery mobile 1.4(I am using Single page model - page1 and page2 within single html file)

Below is the code for what I have tried so far. Please help me resolve this.

Question,

1. How do I restrict direct access of page2. `http://localhost:8080/myApp/#Page2`
2. Is this correct design to handle session from client side?
3. After hitting the url `http://localhost:8080/myApp/#Page2` directly in the browser window.I see that page2 is appearing and then disappearing and finally page1 is appearing.I want to show directly page1 if SessionID is not there in the sessionStorage object.

What I am doing wrong?? Please correct me.

my.js file

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate','#page2', function(event) {
    var SessionID = sessionStorage.getItem("SessionID");
    if(SessionID) {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', "#page2");
    }else {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', "#page1");
    }

});
$(document).on("pageinit","#page1",function() {
$.ajax({
            url : "/myApp/rest/fetchJson",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : formData,
            contentType : "application/json",
            cache : false,
            success : function(data) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("SessionID", data.SessionID);
                    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', "#page2", {
                    transition: 'none'
                }); 
            }
        }); //Ajax ends
}); //page init ends
```

Thanks,

Ashu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create a method javascript to verify if the session exist with ajax request :

```
var sessionExist: function () {

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'checksession_file_onserver',
            data : params,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
 }
```

on file server :

```
if(session_exist){
   return true;
}else {
  return false;
}
```

page to restrict direct access :

```
var sessionStatus = sessionExist();
if(sessionStatus === false) {
  redirect to page ->> example location.hash = 'your page'     
}
```

Comment: @Cesar... So the idea is sessionExist() function will be the first ajax call in my script to find if the user is in  session and if so, render the requested pages. This looks clean and simple. Thank you very much for the guidance.It helped me lot.